# How to edit Sitecore MVP nomination?

Tags: community, mvp

I have recently applied for Sitecore MVP nominations 2017. When i looked at my confirmation email, I found I made a mistake.

- Is there a way to edit it?
- Is it better to reapply for the MVP nominations?
- Is reapplying going to affect in any negative way?

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**UPDATE:** as of Nov 2018 the MVP applications can be saved and edited on the form before finally submitting the information.

---

There is no way to edit your nomination and please do not reapply. You can email your problem to mvp-program@sitecore.net and the team there would be really happy to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I would simply reply on the confirmation and explain your situation. Don't think you'll get any penalties if you complete your nomination before November 30th. Just don't re-apply as this will cause lots of confusion.