# What to do if I received the Sitecore MVP recommendations on my office email id and not on the email ID applied through?

Tags: community, mvp

I have applied for Sitecore MVP through my Gmail account as I have most of accounts, including the Sitecore Developer Network, the rest of the community site and others link to my Gmail account. But some MVP has recommended me through my official email ID.

So what should I do?

Should I forward the recommendation confirmation email which I have received on my official ID to mvp-program@sitecore.net. I can copy the Gmail ID also when I forward the recommendation confirmation email.

Please suggest for best move forward.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Every Sitecore MVP related questions can be sent to the MVP team: mvp-program@sitecore.net**

*Follow the updates of the review and selection process on our Twitter https://twitter.com/SitecoreMVP*

Answer (score 6):

In a previous post ([How to edit Sitecore MVP nomination](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/2939/how-to-edit-sitecore-mvp-nomination/2941#2941))  Tamas Varga wrote to write a email to mvp-program@sitecore.net . I guess in your case you need to do same thing.

Answer (score 3):

I have the same situation. They said to me this is no issue, all nominations and recommendations are matched manually and they would handle it. Just to be sure, you can reply to the notification mail which you received after submitting your nomination.

Comment: Ok, I will forward the recommendation emails to mvp-program@sitecore.net and inform them that I have filled up my nomination through another email account.